# Separate or single use case diagram for two sub-systems?

Tags: uml

I am a newbie in system design and I am having some confusions on creating use case design. I am making a web system with API support sub-system which will be consumed by the android app. The web system and API will be produced as separate app bus use same data layer and are totally in different server (Tomcat-Web system and Jetty server-API). So, my question is that do I need to produce separate Use case design for each web system and API system or make single which will contain functions of both. And I am confused that if I make single use case diagram, then while producing class diagram, the domain object of two system might be related but in the actual implementation the web and api system will be a separate app.

Answer (score 1):

Use cases are related to one "system under consideration" where they appear at the boundary. They describe how the SUC and the environment interact.

If you decide to divide the SUC into sub-systems you will have multiple boundaries. Those boundaries may appear at the outer bounds of the SUC as well as inside. The simplest way to do that is to use packaging structures. This way you can create any type of sub-system. Even sub-sub-system and so on.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective that is less a technical decision and more a didactic one. Use case diagrams should give the reader an overview, the so called big picture of the system. So it depends on you. I see no problem in connecting actors with several subsystems but thats not important for the use case diagram since there are other uml diagrams that are made for this. Plus you should have in mind that use cases diagrams are not meant to focus on things like certain servers. They are meant to show which actor has which possibility to use system use cases and they should stand and the very beginning of the design process - in a state where you ideally shouldn't know that you will use certain servers.